why the particular solution takes this form?
I am trying to find the particular solution of
$$
x^{\prime\prime}-3x^{\prime}-4x=5e^{-t}
$$
I was always taught that the particular solution takes the same form as the non-homogenious part $5e^{-t}$. So I tried $x_p=Ae^{-t}$. However, I found that this doesn't work and instead the solution takes the form $x_p=Ate^{-t}$.
Can you please explain to me why this is?

Because $-1$ is a root of $r^2-3r-4=0$.

Because $e^{-t}$ is already a solution to the homogeneous problem. In consequence, you need to try for another particular solution.
